# Analysis of Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, elliptic-pde

I just wanted to know wthether the following is OK or not.

Let $X$ be $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, thought of as a subspace of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and endowed **solely** with the usual $H^1$ norm.

Let $Y=\{u \in H_0^1(\Omega): ||u||_{\infty}\leq M, ||\nabla u||_{2}\leq r\}$. I want to prove that $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$ under the $H^1$ topology.

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ with $||..||_{1,2}$ norm and hence $||u_n||_{1,2}\leq r$. Hence, $u_n$ converges to $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. So, $||u||_{1,2}\leq ||u_n-u||_{1,2}+||u_n||_{1,2}\leq \epsilon+r$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Hence $||u||_{1,2}\leq r$. Now that $||u_n||_{\infty}\leq M$, hence $0\leq ||u||_{\infty}=\inf_{n}\sup_{x\in \Omega}\{|u_n(x)|\}\leq M$. Thus $Y$ is closed in $X$.

Note that $\frac{Mm(\Omega)^{1/2}}{c(\Omega)} \leq r$, where $C(\Omega)$ is the constant in the Poincare inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't even need to look at Cauchy sequences, since you want to show that $Y$ is closed in some bigger space, whereas you bothered to show completeness.

Other than that, the norms are always continuous with respect to themselves, so the closedness of your conditions defining $Y$ are rather clear. Basically, that's like showing that the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed.

---

**Edit** : I misunderstood the original intent of the question, sorry. One way to prove that the bound is preserved under weak convergence is the following.

From the strong convergence in $H^1_0$ of the sequence $(u_n)$, we have, for $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$,

$$\int_{\Omega} u_n \varphi \to \int_{\Omega} u \varphi \text{ as } n \to \infty. $$

But, by assumption, we also have

$$\left|\int_{\Omega} u_n \varphi \right| \leq M \|\varphi\|_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$

Taking the limit in the inequality, we get

$$\left|\int_{\Omega} u \varphi \right| \leq M \|\varphi\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$$

for any smooth $\varphi$. Thus, $u$ is actually bounded, with $L^{\infty}$ norm no greater than $M$, which closes the proof.

Comment: Thanks Hachino. BTW the reason what I was actually looking for was the following. Since the space $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, I was wondering whether the set $\overline{B_{H_0^1}(0,r)}\bigcap\overline{B_{L^{\infty}}(0,M)}$ is closed w.r.t. $||..||_{1,2}$ norm or not.

Comment: The main doubt in the question was to find out whether the limit function $u$ is bounded by $M$ or not. Clearly it is bounded by $r$ w.r.t. $||..||_{1,2}$ but what about $M$?. In other words what guarantees $||u_n||_{\infty}\rightarrow||u||_{\infty}$?.

Comment: On $X$, one on the most natural norms to put is the sum of $|| \cdot ||_{1,2}$ and $|| \cdot ||_{L^{\infty}}$. Convergence for this norm implies in particular convergence in $L^{\infty}$, which obviously preserves the bound on the $L^{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: I do not want $||..||_{\infty}$ norm on my space $X$ (my problem doesn't allow me to) which is why I have got this problem. The space should solely have $||..||_{1,2}$ norm. The so called "bigger space" $X$ is not closed w.r.t. the $||..||_{1,2}$ norm!.

Comment: @Alexander : Well, that's something you should have mentioned in the first place. Let me correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer Hachino. This should do. Thanks once again!.

Comment: @Alexander : 'Twas my pleasure. :) Also, once you're satisfied with an answer, it is good practice to accept it. It prevents cluttering of the front page by old, long forgotten questions, among other things.